# Rails - link_to remote action won't change html element

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link set up to enable/disable visibility. It updates the database fine, but the icon on the page doesn't change. How do I update the icon when the value is changed in the database?

```
- if v.visibility?
  = link_to version_path(v, version: {visibility: 0}), method: :put, remote: true do
    .mi visibility
- else
  = link_to version_path(v, version: {visibility: 1}), method: :put, remote: true do
    .mi visibility_off
```

Comment: _"How do I update the icon when the value is changed in the database?"_ - if the page doesn't refresh then you have to use JS to change the icon, otherwise add some classes with desired icons to each link element.

Answer (score 1):

The content on the page doesn't change when there is a change in the database until you are using AJAX or any such technology. You will have to fire a request from server to change the content in your web page, or refreshing the page would obviously show the latest page.

Regarding your code, you can better write it this way:

```
- link_to_if v.visibility? do
  = link_to version_path(v, version: {visibility: v.visibility}), method: :put, remote: true do
.mi visibility
```

You can simply use [`link_to_if`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if), and write your code in a better way.